# How parse String contains negative number in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am taking input number from user and then check if the number is positive, negative or zero. Positive number and zero checking performed but having problem in Negative number checking.

```
use std::io::Write;

fn main(){
    print!("Enter Number: ");
    let mut number = String::new();
    std::io::stdout().flush();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut number);
    let num: u32 = number.trim().parse().unwrap();
}
```

when input is negative number, program becomes panic didn't parsing negative number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you replace `u32` by `i32` in the last line your program is able to handle negative numbers.

`u32` means **unsigned** integer with 32bit width so `parse()` panics when it encounters a negative number. `i32` is a **signed** integer so it works.